# How to create a List from a HTTP response string based on certain conditions?

Tags: json, scala, https, playframework

I am trying to parse the result of a **HTTPS** request in **Scala**.

The **HTTPS** response is a **String** as follows:

```
{
  "rows":
  [
    {
      "log_forwarding_ip":"",
      "device_name":"AD1",
      "id":"51",
      "mgmt_ip_addr":"192.168.25.150",
      "log_forwarding":"1",
      "isActive":"0"
    },
    {
      "log_forwarding_ip":"192.168.1.1",
      "device_name":"WIN-SRV2019",
      "id":"50",
      "mgmt_ip_addr":"192.168.25.151",
      "log_forwarding":"1",
      "isActive":"1"
    },
    {
      "log_forwarding_ip":"129.168.1.2",
      "device_name":"PA",
      "id":"3",
      "mgmt_ip_addr":"192.168.1.161",
      "log_forwarding":"1",
      "isActive":"1"
    }
  ],
  "status":1
}
```

I have to create a **List** of all `id`'s where **isActive** and **log_forwarding** are both equal to `1`.

So far what I have done is:

```
object syncTables {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    case class deviceInfo(log_forwarding_ip: String, device_name: String, id: String, 
                          mgmt_ip_addr: String, log_forwarding: String, isActive: String)
    try {
      val r = requests.get("https://192.168.1.253/api/device/deviceinfo.php", verifySslCerts = false)
      if (r.statusCode == 200) {
        val x = r.text
        println(x)
      } else {
        println("Error in API call: "+r.statusCode)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm really confused what to do next to achieve my result. 
I'm totally new to **JSON**, that's why I don't know which **JSON** library I should use.
I tried using **Play Framework** but it seems all pretty complicated to me.

Does `Scala` offer something like `Python`'s `json` module where this task can be easily done by using `dictionaries` and `lists`.

I'm using `Scala 2.11.12` and `com.lihaoyi.requests`.
Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have JSON libraries with parsers, for example [Circe](https://github.com/circe/circe) is one of the most used in Scala

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) to parse the JSON string. Let's call your JSON input string `json`, then you can do something like this

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

case class DeviceInfo(log_forwarding_ip: String, device_name: String, id: String,
                      mgmt_ip_addr: String, log_forwarding: String, isActive: String)

implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats  // Brings in default date formats etc.

val parsedJson = parse(json)
val deviceInfos = parsedJson match {
  case JObject(head :: _) =>
    head._2
      .extract[List[DeviceInfo]]
      .filter(_.isActive == 1 && _.log_forwarding == 1)
}
```

This will output

```
val res0: List[DeviceInfo] = List(DeviceInfo("192.168.1.1","WIN-SRV2019","50","192.168.25.151","1","1"),DeviceInfo("129.168.1.2","PA","3","192.168.1.161","1","1"))
```

Comment: I didn't do it.

Comment: @SarthakPundir If this solves your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)